# Sliding window time complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I have this sliding window algorithms for problem;`Given a string s and a non-empty string p, find all the start indices of p's anagrams in s.`
People said the running time of this algorithm is `o(len(s))` and I'd like to make sure that if I understand it correctly.

So the outer while is `o(len(s))` (assume map look up is o(1)) and the inner while loop also can run for `o(len(s))` in worst case. For exmaple, if `S` is `axyzzzzzzzbc` and `P` is `abc` then the inner while loop moves the start pointer to the end so it will be `o(len(s) + len(s))` so it's `o(2len(s))` but we drop constant so the final run time is `o(len(s))`.

Please let me know if this is correct.

```
public List<Integer> findAnagrams(String s, String p) {
    List<Integer> ret = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (Character c : p.toCharArray()) {
        map.put(c, map.get(c) == null ? 1 : map.get(c) + 1);
    }
    int b = 0, i = 0;
    int c = map.size();
    while (i < s.length()) {
        if (map.containsKey(s.charAt(i))) {
            int t = map.get(s.charAt(i)) - 1;
            map.put(s.charAt(i), t);
            if (t == 0) c--;
        }
        i++;
        while (c == 0) {
            if (map.containsKey(s.charAt(b))) {
                int t = map.get(s.charAt(b)) + 1;
                map.put(s.charAt(b), t);
                if (t > 0) c++;
                    c++;
            }
            if (i - b == p.length()) {
                ret.add(b);
            }
            b++;

        }
    }
    return ret;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, complexity is linear.
Most chars are treated twice - except for last `M=p.length-1` ones.

So `O(N + N - M) = O(N)`

Comment: if (i - b == p.length()) {
                ret.add(b);
}
this will cover the case ..

Comment: Sorry, missed this condition in the second loop.